# Adding a coded animation in Splash Screen iOS Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, launch-screen

I've been trying to add one of this coded cool animations I found https://iosexample.com/fancy-and-beautiful-loaders-for-you-awesome-apps/ in my launch screen (splash screen) when my app first starts. My intuition was to create a LaunchScreen UIViewController class, link it to the LaunchScreen.storyboard, and insert the code there. Unfortunately I haven't found much documentation on that and I've read that apple does not allow to run code on launchscreen. Do you know what could be a possible solution to this? Thanks

Comment: Apple doesn't allow you to run animation on `Launchscreen.storyboard`. Instead, duplicate your launch screen into your initial `ViewController`, then run your animation there.

Answer (score 0):

use Main storyboard ViewController to splash add animation on it, if want like that then go in targets -> General -> Deployment Info -> set Main Interface to Main Storyboard because you need to remove launch screen and also set in launch screen file..
Thanks hope it works!